# Serial communication between different devices

Tags: serial, digital-communications

How is serial communication implemented across different devices?
What is device X is transmitting data to device Y, but X runs at 100MHz.
Is there some kind of communication to set the clock of device Y before it starts to clock the data in?

How would you then transform the serial received data into parallel data that you need for another device? Shift registers?

For example if if im sending 100 bits, but every 5 bits i need to shift them out in parallel to another device, how would i do that?

Comment: You can find a wealth of information on this topic if you search for the term "UART" or "SPI" or "I2C", to give just a few simple examples.

Comment: Hi Linus, let me underline Elliot's answer. This is a WELL understood problem solved in a variety of ways to meet different needs. Please take a peek at the "Serial Communication" Wikipedia entry for a jumping off point. We'll happily answer questions you have about one of those protocols when you get there.

Comment: That would depend on what kind of serial communication you mean. You might want to open up what you mean in your question, so please edit it in. In general, you'd set both devices to use same settings in order to communicate with each other, regardless of at what speed the devices run internally. That's how for example multi-gigahertz computers can communicate with MCUs running at few hundred kilohertz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you then transform the serial received data into parallel
> data that you need for another device? Shift registers?

It depends on if the data has a clock or not, with UARTs (universal asynchronous reciever transmitter) there receiver has to know what the timing of the data is (so it can be synced to the incoming data). With clocked data you can use a shift register, most devices are more complicated than that because they have multiple addressable devices and/or registers to send receive data.

> For example if if im sending 100 bits, but every 5 bits i need to
> shift them out in parallel to another device, how would i do that?

Use a state machine or counter to count every 5 bits, after 5 bits have passed then output the 5 bits out of the shift register (or pulse an enable line to make them valid).

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use shift registers, but an easy way to do it would be to use a microcontroller with both UART and parallel interfaces as peripherals. You just store the data to memory on read, and write it out to whatever peripheral(s) needs it.

Answer (score 0):

There are self clocking protocols and externally clocked protocols. As long as the channel medium supports the BW of the signal with adequate SNR, the conversion to parallel depends on the detection of sync.

This can be externally sync’d or self-sync’d using patterns for starting frame sync from which agreed upon byte boundaries and but sync options as above.

For example the original 1.544 Mbps digital telephony =T1 or DS1 over long-hauls was self-clocking using bipolar RZ or BiPhase to extract the clock.  These were framed into 24x8 bit time slots with 64kbps channels. Additional data used one time slot’s lsb knowing that with over 76 dB of compressed voice the noise would never be noticed. These bit rates are exceptionally clock stable and traceable to a nuclear clock which made the synchronization that much easier to merge multiple sources of data.

But Async channels, although less efficient are easily synchronized by the leading start bit edge and knowing the bit rate, n bits, parity option and stop bit